# Rastrear tráfico por un puerto WireShark

Tags: tcpip, wireshark

Tengo un thread que corre en un puerto concreto (digamos el 55000), necesito filtrar todo lo que sale y entra por ese puerto.
Así que utilizo el filtro

> dst port 55000

En WireShark, sin embargo no pilla nada.
De hecho, haciendo un telnet a ese puerto y tocando botones a saco sigue sin imprimir ningún paquete. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Prueba con tcp.port ==55000

Comment: creo que debes de establecer una captura con el modulo de pcap, me parece que existe una funcion que engloba este modulo para c# y podras configurar los parametros de entrada y salida sobre un puerto en concreto.